# Test output not visible in Jenkins build log

Tags: python, python-3.x, jenkins, pytest, stdout

I want to see stdout coming from a python test inside the jenkins build logs. I'm running pytest (==5.3.1) from within my Jenkins pipeline inside an sh script:

```
stage('unit tests') {            
     print "starting unit tests"
     sh script: """
         source env-test/bin/activate && \
         python -m pytest -x -s src/test/test*.py
     """, returnStdout: true, returnStatus: true
}
```

Note that I'm running my tests from with a virtual environment (env-test).
Unfortunately, the Jenkins logs do not display output that I send from within my tests:

```
def test_it(self):
   print('\nhello world')
   self.assertTrue(True)
```

But it only shows the initial call:

```
+ python -m pytest -x -s src/test/testModel.py
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // stage
```

Whereas my local pycharm ide and gitbash shows all output:

```
============================= test session starts =============================
platform win32 -- Python 3.6.4, pytest-5.3.1, py-1.8.0, pluggy-0.13.1 --     C:\...\Anaconda3\python.exe
cachedir: .pytest_cache
rootdir: C:\...\src\test
collecting ... collected 1 item

testModel.py::TestModel::test_it
PASSED                                  [100%]
hello world

============================== 1 passed in 0.57s ==============================
```

The pytest docs are talking about [Capturing of the stdout/stderr output](https://docs.pytest.org/en/latest/capture.html#setting-capturing-methods-or-disabling-capturing). So I tried to use the -s parameter in order to disable capturing but without success.

Answer (score 0):

The issue was the [returnStdout parameter](https://jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/steps/workflow-durable-task-step/) of the groovy sh script command:

> returnStdout (optional) If checked, standard output from the task is
>   returned as the step value as a String, rather than being printed to
>   the build log. (Standard error, if any, will still be printed to the
>   log.) You will often want to call .trim() on the result to strip off a
>   trailing newline. Type: boolean

So I simply remove that option from the sh script command.